# Xcode поиск строки вызывающей исключение

Tags: ios, xcode, отладка

Как в отладчике Xcode найти (перейти) к строке objective-c на которой падает программа?
Ассемблерный  код остановки программы мне непонятен, в логе информация о недопустимом индексе обращения к массиву, но искать в каком месте это происходит долго. Может есть простой цивилизованный способ?

Comment: в логе обычно весь стэктрейс выводится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способы есть, конечно. Подозреваю, что не один. Я пользуюсь следующим приёмом:

перейдите в breakpoint navigator

[image: перейдите в breakpoint navigator]

выберите пункт add exception breakpoint

[image: выберите пункт add exception breakpoint]

все опции оставьте по умолчанию. запускайте приложение.

вот таким будет итог данных манипуляций:

[image: вот таким будет итог данных манипуляций]

Comment: Repax, спасибо! Этот способ сильно облегчает отладку.